# checking for the \n character, but nothing after that

Tags: c++

We are working on trying to get a simple program to either say a turtle has laid eggs or not, based on user input.

The turtle starts with 8 eggs and only lays one when the user presses Enter. ('\n').

We have finally got it to work in the sense that if we press Enter, it will say the turtle lays an egg and counts down to 0 eggs left. It will also say that no egg was laid if you type anything else.

The issue we are having is to keep it from returning the 'else' statement multiple times if someone inputs more than one incorrect character we used the cin.ignore command.

However, we questioned what would happen if we only put in cin.ignore(10, '\n'), and the input was more than 10 characters. The answer is that it repeats the 'else' statement of not laying an egg.

Is there a way to just clear the input stream after the first character so the input can be as much as they want, and it will still only return one line (either laid an egg or not) for each input?

Here is the code.

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int eggs = 8;
    char input;

    while (eggs > 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter input: ";
        cin.get(input);

        if (input == '\n')
        {
            cout << "Raphie laid an egg because you pressed enter.\n";
            eggs--;
            cout << "She has " << eggs << " left.\n";
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Raphie didn't lay an egg.\n";
            cin.ignore(10, '\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not really sure why the code didnt full format, but the part in question looks ok, so i will leave it.

Comment: convention is that all code lines begin with 4 spaces. You will get used to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use...

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

...to ignore any amount of input before the newline.

Comment: I'll have to look into std::streamsize. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well usually you'd want to either read in lines or single characters. Notice how '\n' fits in both categories.

If you still want (or have) to stick with ignoring characters, you could try ignoring exactly `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`, which is the maximum number of characters in a stream at any given time.

Comment: I'm not attached to any method. I just want to find a way to use \n as input/conditional to perform the task. Would you suggest another method? I'm sure you can tell but I'm just starting to learn so the less complex the better.

Comment: The easiest option would be to either stick with single key presses (<press 'n' - no, press 'y' - yes> kind of thing) or whole lines (type "lay eggs" to lay eggs or anything else to do nothing).

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()

{

using namespace std;

int eggs = 8;
char input;

while (eggs > 0)
{
    cout << "Enter input: ";
    cin.get(input);

    if (input == '\n')
    {
        if (eggs > 0)
        {
            cout << "Raphie laid an egg because you pressed enter.\n";
            eggs--;
            cout << "She has " << eggs << " left.\n";
        }
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Raphie didn't lay an egg.\n";
        cin.ignore(10, '\n');
    }
}

return 0;
}
```